# Python : Finding all rows in a dataframe where a particular column value sums to 0

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extract all rows in a dataframe where the sum of a particular column of these grouped rows is 0.

eg : if I have below rows :

```
Row 1 1000
Row 2 -1000
Row 3 6000
Row 4 8000
```

I would group Row1 and Row 2 since the sum of the column is 0(+1000-1000=0)
How do I do this in python? How can I use numpy to achieve this?

Comment: DO you also want to group more then two lines? E.g.: r1: 1, r2: -1, r3:10, r4:-10 -> r1:0?

Comment: Do you want to consider only adjacent rows or would r1 and r2 still be grouped if they were in first and third position?

Comment: yes..it can be any number of rows/lines, but the sum should be 0

Comment: @ Lukas Thaler :yes...I would want to group r1 and r2 even if there are in 1& 3 rd position

Comment: @Lazloo Xp : yes in the example you mentioned r1 and r2 would form a group,say G1 and r3 and r4 would form another group, say G2.  or it can be r1+r2+r3+r4=0 with a single group(G1)

Comment: Could any row be used in multiple groups?

Comment: That means you are loooking for the rows that are in sum euqal to the total sum. In your example 14000

Comment: Does group size matter? For example, [5, -5, 2, 3], has two possible groups. If multiple groups would not be allowed, is [5, -5] preferred, or [-5, 2, 3]?

Comment: @0 0 : 5,-5 is preferred, but multiple groups will do as well

Comment: @Lazloo Xp : I dont need the sum of all rows, but only those rows whose sum =0 . In my example row 1 and 2 's sum is equal to 0. So my output should have row1&2 since their sum=0

Comment: But do you want both [5, -5] and [-5, 2, 3] from that example? See my first question/comment: can a row be used multiple times?

Comment: I don't know of any numpy or pandas algorithm that can help you here. This may very well be something you have to do yourself, and is probably O(2) (or more, depending on your specifications).

Comment: 0-0 : yes I want both [5,-5] and [-5,2,3]

Comment: If you are talking about dataframes, add a pandas tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a more instructive result, I extended your sample DataFrame to:

```
   Id  Amount
0   1    1000
1   2   -1000
2   3   -5000
3   4    6000
4   5    8000
5   6   -2000
6   7   -4000
7   8   -2000
8   9    1500
9  10     500
```

You can generate "pairs of border row indices" the following way:

```
result = []
# Starting from each row, except the last
for i in range(df.index.size - 1):
    # Compute expanding sum
    s = df.iloc[i:].expanding().Amount.sum()
    # Find indices of zeroes
    ind = s[s == 0].index
    # Append "start == i, end == j" to the result
    result.extend([ [i, j] for j in ind ])
```

The result is:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 3], [1, 7], [4, 7], [7, 9]]
```

To retrieve, print and check presented "ranges" of rows, run:

```
for i, j in result:
    print(f'From {i} to {j}:')
    print(df.iloc[i:j+1])
    print(f'Sum: {df.iloc[i:j+1].Amount.sum()}\n')
```

The result is:

```
From 0 to 1:
   Id  Amount
0   1    1000
1   2   -1000
Sum: 0

From 1 to 3:
   Id  Amount
1   2   -1000
2   3   -5000
3   4    6000
Sum: 0

From 1 to 7:
   Id  Amount
1   2   -1000
2   3   -5000
3   4    6000
4   5    8000
5   6   -2000
6   7   -4000
7   8   -2000
Sum: 0

From 4 to 7:
   Id  Amount
4   5    8000
5   6   -2000
6   7   -4000
7   8   -2000
Sum: 0

From 7 to 9:
   Id  Amount
7   8   -2000
8   9    1500
9  10     500
Sum: 0
```

## Edit following the comment as of 12:52Z

If you want **only** "leaf level" ranges (not included in wider ranges)
then after you find some indices of zeroes (in the rolling sum), you should
report **only the first** range, because other ranges include just the
already reported range.

So the code should be changed to:

```
result = []
# Starting from each row, except the last
for i in range(df.index.size - 1):
    # Compute expanding sum
    s = df.iloc[i:].expanding().Amount.sum()
    # Find indices of zeroes
    ind = s[s == 0].index   
    if ind.size > 0:        # Something found
        result.append([i, ind[0]])  # Append "from i to the first 'zero row'"
```

Note that:

- I added *if* to avoid "index out of range" exception if no "zero sum"
  has been found,
- changed *extend* into *append*, because:

  - in the previous version I wanted the list of pairs to be "decomposed"
    and each pair added separately to the result,
  - now I add only a **single** pair, which should **not** be "decomposed".

This time the result is:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 3], [4, 7], [7, 9]]
```

and note that range *[1, 7]* (present in the first solution) has not been added.

So now you have only ranges that don't include other ranges.

Comment: Valdi_Bo : Could you also help me with other version where once you have a  r1 and r2 as part of a group , I don't want to be included in other group. In my case,1000  & -1000 are already grouped, so I don't want them to be part of larger group. Priority is given to smaller groups first

Comment: Thank you so much Valdi_Bo. I actually tried this on the below dataframe: Amount
0 1000
1 -1000
2 2000
3 2000
4 2000
5 -2000
6 -3000 and it continues to give me rows which are in other ranges as well...Guess I need to put a check to see if index is already present in result.If yes, then exclude the range

Comment: Hi Valdi_Bo : I tried this for the below amount.Doesnt work for this. Could you please help? :Amount
1000
-32024.43
134.92
-2000
31889.51
-2000
-1000    Row 1& 7 form a group, Row 2,3,5 form another group and Row 4,6 format a group

Comment: My code checks sums of **consecutive** values. A case like "row 1 and 7" aren't taken into account. To perform seach like this, you should generate combinations without repetitions. But then it is hard to state whether one such "group" includes other group. Note also that in your post you initially presented a case of just **consecutive** elements, so I assumed that this is the way the code should operate.

Comment: My bad. I did not mention that point initially. But can we do this ? How to generate combinations

Comment: Use *itertools* package. It contains a.o. *combinations* method. Search the Web for examples and instructions.

Comment: Sure..let me give a try. Thank you so much